# Rails, Devise custom views for specific models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, devise

I have model `Partner` with its controllers and a lot of views. Then I added `Devise` to this model.

I wanted to customize views of registration and login, so i made this command:

```
rails generate devise:views partners
```

It generated to me new views in `views/partners` folder. I opened `partners/registrations/new.html.erb` file and edited this form. When I open `sign up` page it shows me old form not my edited. Why?

**UPDATE**

I just needed to add  `config.scoped_views = true` inside my `config/initializers/devise.rb` file.

I have added new fields for my form and they aren't persisting. In Devise site they say to use `configure_permitted_parameters` inside my application controller to make devise accept values of new form elements.

However, I will have a multiple models created by devise which got their own fields. They say, that need to create `Sanitizer` classes. Where I must create this `Sanitizer` classes?

Comment: Did u change your routes?

Comment: Check your route and also not forget to restart your server

Comment: Routes? What Routes?

Comment: under `congif/routes.rb` have you put `devise_for :partners` ?

Comment: Yes I have put this line. Do I need to add something more?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Registration#new` will render the `views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`. While u made changes to `views/partners/registrations/new.html.erb`, which explains why u don't see the changes.

**Update:**
If you have multiple devise models, you will define the routes correspondingly. In your case, it could be something like this

```
devise_for :partners, :controllers => {:registrations => "partner_registrations"}
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "user_registrations"}
```

And you can modify their correspoding views in `views/devise/partner_registrations/new.html.erb` and `views/devise/user_registrations/new.html.erb`

While your corresponding Controllers would be

```
#app/controllers/user_registrations_controller.rb
class UserRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    #Your Code Here
end

#app/controllers/partner_registrations_controller.rb
class PartnerRegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    #Your Code Here
end
```

Comment: I have multiple devise models and there will be more. How can I  make that when I try to register as `Partner` it will show my views?

Comment: I have found another way, more simplier. I just needed to add `config.scoped_views = true` inside `config/initializers/devise.rb` file.

Comment: ofc `config.scoped_views` is the first step. You can define Sanitizer class in your Lib folder.

Comment: And I recommend u to refer to `https://github.com/plataformatec/devise` for how to completely configure your devise. It contains complete instructions

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in `devise.rb` called `scoped_views` which is turned off by default, you have to enable it to make sure that you use the custom views in your app rather than from the default devise views.